# Android: How to scale the return value of getMaxAmplitude()?

Tags: android, audio, signal-processing

The return value of this function should be an integer from 0 to 32767 which representing the audio's amplitude.

However, after testing, it is quite easy to reach the maximum value (32767) even a very little voice. For example, a baby cry will output (32767) amplitude. But a little voice will also output (32767) amplitude.

May I ask how can I manage the return value of this function?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your sensor/microphone/decoder responds in range 0 to 100 , so 0 maps to 0 and 100 would map to 32767.

```
ScaleConstant = 32767/100
```

for output of 50:

```
value = 50*ScaleConstant
```

Comment: Thanks. But the problem is that it is quite easy to reach the maximum value. For example, a baby cry will output "32767". But a right click of mouse will also output "32767". It is meaningless thus I would like to ask if there is any method to adjust or over-ride the google's method.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your device is really sensitive to sounds. I had implemented this piece of code before in android before without a problem. I recommend testing it on another device and check if the problem persists or if there is a problem with the code.

The getMaxAmplitude() function returns a value between 0 to +32767 which is an estimate of the loudness of the noise as a measure of sound pressure. To approximately obtain a value in dB, you can use the following code in android which is a direct interpretation of the mathematical equation.

```
20 * Math.log10(mediaRecorderObject.getMaxAmplitude())
```

This returns an approximate dB value.

Another thing I'd suggest is, you calibrate the application with the phone. Before the application starts, you can do a recording in a silent environment. So, if the application running on two different phones shows a value of 4000 and 6000 for the recording in a silent environment, you can add a scaling factor that suits your application.